# C++ inheritance and function overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

In C++, will a member function of a base class be overridden by its derived class function of the same name, **even if its prototype (parameters' count, type and constness)  is different**? I guess this a silly question, since many websites says that the function prototype should be the same for that to happen; but why doesn't the below code compile? It's a very simple case of inheritance, I believe.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {};
class B {};

class X
{
public:
    void spray(A&)
    {
        cout << "Class A" << endl;
    }
};

class Y : public X
{
public:
    void spray(B&)
    {
        cout << "Class B" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    Y y;

    y.spray(a);
    y.spray(b);

    return 0;
}
```

GCC throws

```
error: no matching function for call to `Y::spray(A&)'
note: candidates are: void Y::spray(B&)
```

Comment: Got the C++ FAQ that says about the same issue, for an elaborate explanation if some one requires it :)
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

Comment: It's a bit dangerous to say that the signatures should be the same. Signatures are the basis for name mangling and linking. Two members of different classes always have different signatures, even if one overrides the other. It's better to say "same parameter types, names and constness", i think, even if it is longer to say.

Comment: @litb: Thanks for clarifying! I guess 'prototype' is the apt word here, I've changed it in the question :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The term used to describe this is "hiding", rather than "overriding". A member of a derived class will, by default, make any members of base classes with the same name inaccessible, whether or not they have the same signature. If you want to access the base class members, you can pull them into the derived class with a `using` declaration. In this case, add the following to `class Y`:

```
using X::spray;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that made it clear. It works when I add the using directive here. But when I change the spray signatures to spray(int) in X and spray(float) in Y and call y.spray(1); and y.spray(1.0f); it works without the using directive. How come?

Comment: Wow sorry, my bad, it still is seeing only the spray(float) of Y's, when I do y.spray(1); it type casts the int to float implicitly.

Comment: This is one of those answers that deserves its own special question, crafted with lots of search powder so people can find it better.

Answer (score 9):

That's so called 'hiding': `Y::spray` hides `X::spray`.
Add using directive:

```
class Y : public X
{
public:
   using X::spray;
   // ...
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Classes are scopes and a class scope is nested in its parent.  You have exactly the same behavior with other nested scopes (namespaces, blocks).

What happen is that when the name lookup searches for the definition of a name, it looks in the current namespace, then in the englobing namespace and so on until it find one definition; the search then stop (that's without taking into account the complications introduced by argument dependent name lookup -- the part of the rules which allows to use a function defined in the namespace of one of its argument).

Comment: Thanks for explaining the underlying reason behind the hinding; it really says why I got that error in the first place and why the using directive resolved it.