# Can i use a method overriding a non-virtual method?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I am trying to understand a point here in C++.
If class A has a non-virtual method, and class B, which extends A, overrides that method, can i create an instance of B and somehow use the method defined in B?
Is there a point to override a non-virtual method?

Comment: What you describe is called *hiding*, not overriding. Take a look here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161462/c-inheritance-and-function-overriding

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Is there a point to override a non-virtual method?

You are not actually overriding, but this is the behavior, i.e

```
B* b = new B();
A* a = new B();
b->method(); //Calls B's method
a->method(); // Calls A's method
```

So, the pointer/reference type determines the method called.

> can i create an instance of B and somehow use the method defined in B?

Yes. The pointer/reference type has to be of type B. (see previous example).

If you don't declare `method` to be `virtual`, you cannot **override** it, but you can **hide** it.

Comment: One "gotcha" is the situation when `A` in turn is derived from some base class (or implements an interface) which declares `virtual method()`, in which case `a->method()` will in fact call `B.method()`...

Comment: @Chip You missed to emphasize the difference. This answer is complete only with BadCashs comment.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r While you are right, in BadCash's case A's method is virtual. The question was about non-virtual methods. In C++, "once virtual, always virtual".

Answer (score 13):

If `B` inherits from `A`, and redefines a method defined in `A`, then new instances of `B` will call `B`'s version. However, if the method is not virtual, then there is no polymorphic behavior, so if an instance of `B` is referenced as an `A`, then the method will be `A`'s. For example:

```
struct A {
    void foo () { std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A {
    void foo () { std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl; }
};

B b;
b.foo();
A *a = &b;
a->foo();
```

The output of the code above would be:

```
B::foo
A::foo
```

However, if the `foo` method had been virtual, then `B::foo` would have been printed twice.

Comment: Well written! :)

Answer (score 4):

If a function is not `virtual` then the type of the variable determines which implementation is dispatched too:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    void f() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

struct B : public A {
    void f() { cout << "B" << endl; }
};

int main(int args, char** argv) {

    B b;
    A& a = b;

    b.f();
    a.f();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- No, there is no mechanism to override a non-virtual method in class A.
- Yes, you can use a non-virtual method from class A overloaded in B by using scope resolution operator A::methodName